# Como validar uma coluna baseada em uuid?

Tags: laravel, postgresql

Eu tenho a classe de validação e estou tentando garantir que a coluna de código seja exclusiva com base no uuid

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\Common;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ProjectRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        $uuid = $this -> project ?? ' ';

        return [

            'code' => [ 'required', 'min:2', 'max:255',"unique:common_projects,code,{$uuid},uuid"],
            'description' => [ 'required', 'min:3', 'max:9999' ],
            'coordinator_id' => [ 'nullable' ],

        ];
    }
}
```

Minha rota é: `Route::apiResource('/projects',ProjectController::class);`

Estou usando postgres database.

Quando eu tento inserir um novo registro recebo a mensagem:

> "message": "SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:
> invalid input syntax for type uuid: " " (SQL: select count(*) as
> aggregate from "common_projects" where "code" = test and "uuid"
> <>  )",
> "exception": "Illuminate\Database\QueryException",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema fazendo

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\Common;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ProjectRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        $uuid = $this -> project ?? ' ';

        return [

            'code' => [ 'required', 'min:2', 'max:255',Rule::unique('common_projects')->ignore($uuid)],
            'description' => [ 'required', 'min:3', 'max:9999' ],
            'coordinator_id' => [ 'nullable' ],

        ];
    }
}
```